# Jenkins build Visual Studio Solution with Different Configuration

Tags: visual-studio-2012, jenkins, msbuild

Hi I have a **visual studio solution** which has been configured in **Jenkins**. And it's building successfully in debug configuration. How ever I need to change the build configuration to Release or another different one.

So How can I configure Jenkins to select the configuration to build?

Comment: How are you starting the debug build from Jenkins?

Comment: Can you provide the exact command line you are using?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the MSBuild plugin, try adding the configuration flag on the "Command Line Arguments" section:
 /p:Configuration=Release

If you are simply building from command line script (batch, powershell, etc), add the above flag there..

What I do, is create a generic job for build process which receives a parameter called "BUILD_CONFIGURATION" from the parent job which triggers it.
And I then reference it in the flag as a variable:
 /p:Configuration=${BUILD_CONFIGURATION}